# How to uninstall the default Camera application - Freya

Tags: release-freya, applications, camera

How can I uninstall the default Camera application in Freya by command.

I tried following commands, but none of them works, could you help me on this. thanks in advance

```
sudo apt-get purge snap
sudo apt-get purge snap-elementary
```

Best regards
Yuhua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To uninstall the default camera application (snap) run the following in a terminal.

```
sudo apt-get remove snap-photobooth
```

Remember to mark as answer if it works

Answer (score 0):

As ElementaryOS team gravitated towards pushing the default apps as containerized Flatpaks. The current camera app -and many others- can be removed through the flatpak client itself. The command to go is

```
sudo flatpak uninstall io.elementary.camera
```